# Angular 4 inserting file name in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi I am looping through name of pdf file with small display.

```
<div *ngFor="let file of files >
  <object width="100p" height="50"  data="./info/{{file.filename}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>
```

Problem I have is that

```
 data="./info/{{file.filename}}"   should substitute file name and should be like   data="/info/xyz.pdf"
```

But I get error of filename undefined. 
Please let me know how can i correct this to display filename properly.
THanks

Comment: show how you are sending files variable.

Comment: I dont know if you are familiar with object tag. Basically when it gets file name with path it displays pdf file. files is a list coming from database which is working fine.I can display them with alert or console.log(file.filename) it shows xyz.pdf problem is syntax "./info/{{file.filename}}"   where if i insert direct file name like "./info/xyz.pdf" it works fine. So it is syntax issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log` is giving you the wrong impression because `file.filename` is still `undefined` by the time the object tries to render. Make it wait for the file to be available before rendering the object with `*ngIf` like:

```
<div *ngFor="let file of files >
  <object *ngIf="file?.filename" width="100p" height="50"  data="./info/{{file.filename}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>
```

This is called [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#safe-navigation-operator).

Comment: also while at it, check `async` pipe.